# Shorter name for “non-blocking with background synchronization?”

Tags: word-choice

What would be a short, human name (so that support dude can spell it) for a concept where user action is non-blocking and state is synchronized in the background?

In my case I mark some clients as having really crap network and thus force them into such mode of operation.

Normal mode of operation is on-line, synchronous, blocking, live, soft real-time and ignores cached data.

Modern "offline html5" application do this, AJAX does it, Unix AIO does it, but what is it called?

Candidates so far

```
asynchronous (spelling)
non-blocking
offline (unclear)
batched (incorrect)
network-challenged ()
cached (Tomasz)
delayed
...
...
...
```

(cross-posted on stackoverflow)

(too bad lads decided to close this down, "human word for technical term asynchronous" is a valid question, and will continue to be pertinent until the whole world goes online)

Comment: 'in the background'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asynchronous is the correct term. It would probably be appropriate to shorten it to async, which should prove less troublesome from the spelling perspective - not that you wont get other versions, just that it is easier to interpret.

The other term that might work is "out-of-process", which is strictly correct, doesn't suffer the same spelling issues, but might not be comprehensible.

"Batched", thought strictly speaking wrong, may work, because the implications of a batched process are still present. As long as everyone technical understands what is meant.

Comment: Wonder how async could be 'correct' with the background sync.

Comment: As I understand it, the process are happening asynchronously to the user processing - i.e. non-blocking. That is async.